# Why does building my native react android app after implementing facebook sdk gives me these errors?

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, sdk

I did the [tutorial on facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native) for using the facebook sdk for my react native android app exactly as its documented but I get the following errors when I try to run `$react-native run-android`:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this tutorial 
https://tylermcginnis.com/installing-the-facebook-sdk-into-a-react-native-android-and-ios-app/
There are some missing pieces with the fbsdk official.
The above link will definitely solve your problem.
I have successfully implemented it.